# How to format cp command or ditto in terminal MAC OS X to copy source to multiple destinations

Tags: macos, cp

How to format cp command or ditto in terminal to copy source to multiple destinations? I am completely unexperienced in using terminal but have heard that is copies faster and I have large batched to send to multiple USB flash drives all titled NO NAME, NO NAME 1, NO NAME 2, etc etc

Answer (score -1):

Did you try?

```
cp -r source target1 target2 targetN
```

Comment: No and trying to just copy to the USB device ended up making a folder in my home folder with the same name 

I was using this:  sudo rsync -vaE --progress ~/Desktop/WBCSP17 /Volumes/NO NAME

Comment: Also not sure how to format the target names correctly